# How to set StrictHostKeyChecking=no for SFTP using java // jscape

Tags: java, sftp

I am using SFTP using manual command as

```
sftp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

How to pass same StrictHostKeyChecking=no using java

Current there is a java class that does like this

```
final com.jscape.inet.ssh.util.SshParameters sshParameters =
                new SshParameters("host",
                        "port",
                        "userid",
                        "password");

com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp sftp= new  com.jscape.inet.sftp.Sftp(sshParameters);
```

How to pass or provide same behavior as StrictHostKeyChecking=no in the above java code. Examples that I was able to search talk about SCP.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library.  I can't even find it in the standard Maven repositories, and all I can find online is its Javadocs.  So I can't try what I'm suggesting here.  This is just what I see in the Javadocs.

The SshParameters object you are creating has a `setHostKeyVerifier` method, and the class it takes, `HostKeyVerificationService`, has a static implementation called `NULL` that the docs say does no verification.  So what I would try is this:

```
sshParameters.setHostKeyVerifier(HostKeyVerificationService.NULL);
```

Comment: It seems that it is not supported in the version I have. Closest I saw was
```
sshParameters.setHostKeyVerifier(new NullHostKeyVerifier());

but it did not work as it throws same exception as before 

Caused by: com.jscape.inet.ssh.transport.TransportException: cause: java.util.NoSuchElementException: no common elements found
 at com.jscape.inet.ssh.transport.AlgorithmSuite.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.jscape.inet.ssh.transport.TransportClient.getSuite(Unknown Source)
 at com.jscape.inet.ssh.transport.Transport.exchangeKeys(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: No NULL service in your version, eh?  Well, then maybe you have to write your own overload of that class that does no verification.  I'm not sure that's enough even if you get it working.  I was just giving you what I would probably try after looking at the API docs.